# Setting website height css

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a website and i'm trying to fix the max height to 1100px. However if i try do this i get 2 scroll bars coming up assuming because of the div. Could anyone help me? here is a snippet of my code.

CSS:

```
html, body {
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrap { 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: `#wrap { max-height: 1100px }`?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: along with benm's suggestion I would also move the overflow to the `#wrap`

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? Without any HTML, it's impossible to say where the 2 scrollbars come from.

Comment: when i do that in the wrap it makes a scroll bar inside the web page

Comment: and by moving the overflow x all the unwanted width comes back

Comment: http://i299.photobucket.com/albums/mm308/nippy-a7x/Untitled-1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `max-height` property on the your `#wrap` element. It might also be advisable to move the `overflow-x` property, and change it to `overflow-y`, or simply `overflow` too:

```css
html, body {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrap { 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 1100px;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nNZvp/)

## Edit:

I have added `overflow-y` to the `html, body` definition to prevent the default viewport scrollbar from showing.

Comment: thanks that works for the site as a whole, however now my wrap has a scroll bar actually in the webpage. Any idea why?

Comment: Sure. Because `#wrap` is taller than the viewport. I've updated the code to prevent this from showing a scrollbar.

Comment: and i also seem to of lost the contents in my wrap at the top of the page

Comment: Sorry don't know if i'm doing this wrong but that code just makes me unable to scroll down, if it was 1100px i would be able to scroll as i have a small screen

Comment: Huh?! You want to hide the overflow but allow scrolling. Sorry, we'll need to see some code.

Comment: Basically i want the site to be 1100px but not allow x scrolling. IS there any way i can show you both the CSS and HTML file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34456/discussion-between-nick-pocock-and-benm)

Comment: it seems to push all my wrap content down so the overflow goes all the way to near the top and i cant see anything